# Display all ids of a model in text field in erb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a `Quiz` model that `has_many` `questions`. I need to show all the `ids` of `questions` associated with a particular `Quiz` in `text_field`. At present my code is like this:

```
<%= text_field(:quiz, :quiz_questions) %>
```

This displays the object `quiz_questions` but I must display the `ids` of all the `questions` of that `quiz`. I want something like this:

```
<%= text_field(:quiz, :quiz_questions, :id) %>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument `quiz_questions` is your model method. Therefore you need to add one to your model that only returns the `ids`

```
# app/models/quiz.rb

def question_ids
  questions.ids
end
```

in your view

```
<%= text_field(:quiz, :question_ids) %>
```